# Django EditForm not loading existing file with custom widget

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In my Django application I have created a form using forms.py. When I am editing that form I can not see the existing files of that form, yes I have set the instance for that EditForm and I can see other text fields data, I can not see existing data of file input. If I remove the class I added in the widget, then I can see the data. Why is that? And how can I use both widget and see the existing data? Below is my code:

**forms.py:**

```py
class ContentCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    text_instruction = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'accept': '.txt', 'class': 'form-control'})) # If I remove this I can see the existing files
    course_video = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'accept': 'video/*', 'class': 'form-control'})) # If I remove this I can see the existing files
    preview_video = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'accept': 'video/*', 'class': 'form-control'}), required=False) # If I remove this I can see the existing files
    resource_file = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'accept': '.pdf', 'class': 'form-control'})) # If I remove this I can see the existing files

    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py:**

```py
def myView(request, id):
    current_content = Content.objects.get(id=id)
    form = forms.ContentCreateForm(instance=current_content)
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'editForm.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you're not using the fields from your model (you are using a `ModelForm`). I would have to take a look at your model to be sure but i suspect that what you're trying to do is something like this:

```
class ContentCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'course_video' : forms.FileInput(attrs={
                'accept': 'video/*', 
                'class': 'form-control'
            },
            'preview_video' : etc etc {
            })
        }
```

The view seems alright to me.